# Class Variables

Tags: ruby, instance-variables, class-variables, class-instance-variables

Explain please, I can not understand.

```
class Foo
  @a = 123
  @@b = 123
end
```

What are the advantages of variable objects-classes and the class variables? When should I use first, and in which the second?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instance level variables area created anew for each instance of the class.  For example, a variable `@id` should probably be unique for each instance of `Foo`.  However, there may be some values that should be the same for every instance of the type.  In that case, a class variable would be more appropriate.

One important side effect of class level variables is that they **are shared amongst derived classes as well**.  This means that changing the value in a subclass of 'Foo' will change it for 'Foo' objects as well.  This may be what you want, but it can be a bit surprising to find out the hard way.

For example:

```
class Foo
  @@some_var = 1
  def bar
    puts(@@some_var)
  end
end

class Baz < Foo
  def perhaps_unexpected
    @@some_var = 10
    Foo.new.bar  #prints '10'
  end
end
```

Comment: This code prints 3 and nil. Why? `code`class MyClass
 @@global = 3
 @local = 7
 
 def my_print
  puts @@global
  puts @local
 end
end

obj = MyClass.new
obj.my_print`code`

Comment: Because you cannot initialize member variables in the class scope, you need to do it inside of a method (usually the constructor, `initialize`).  From the docs: `An instance variable has a name beginning with @, and its scope is confined to whatever object self refers to.`  In your code `self` does not refer to that class scope, so the variable is uninitialized.

Answer (score 1):

Use a class variable when you want all the instances of the class to share that variable, and use an instance variable when you want each instance to have its own non-shared variable.